# Android EditText show keyboard with capital letters and number row

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I can display a keyboard with capital litters with:

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

but can I show a number row?

With

```
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

I can have the desired display when holding shift in the keyboard
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk9qR.png)

But can I initialize editText to show that?

P.S.: already tried

```
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textCapCharacters"
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `android:textAllCaps="true"` combined with `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"`?
Anyway I don't think it would result the same on every device, since it is keyboard specific, whether it has number row or not.

Comment: Also note, `android:textAllCaps` property exists from API level 14, below you can use the property of AppCompat (with the same name), or `setTransformationMethod` method of `TextView`

Comment: it didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion. As the result might vary, i will keep just the capital letters

Comment: I think it's a bit weird, because if textVisiblePassword input type has resulted the desired thing, except the capital letters, then textAllCaps should make them capital (leastwise that would be logical)

Answer (score 0):

`android:inputType="textCapCharacters"` is only work when your device keyboard Auto Capitalize Setting enabled.

Answer (score -2):

textCapCharacters|textVisiblePassword is working fine for me.